# Need help updating database with data posted from Json in Laravel

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

I am working on a project and making use of bootstrap modal to open an edit form for records in my database. After editing, I am able to submit the data using ajax post to my controller "update". Using $data = Input::all(), I am able to get what is been sent from the submit, and with $test = $data['test'], I'am able to get the individual fields. However, when I get a specific record from my database (can confirm this works using print_r($record)) and make my changes, after I use $record->save(), I get error 500 (Internal Server Error). I can't figure out what the problem is. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanx in advance.

```
**Code below:**
***javascript:***

$('#editForm').on('submit', function(e){
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
                var $form = $('#editForm');
                var projectnr = $form.find('[name="project"]').val();
                var projectpart = $form.find('[name="projectpart"]').val();
                var termnr = $form.find('[name="termnr"]').val();
                var status= $form.find('[name="status"]').val();
                var amount= $form.find('[name="amount"]').val();
                var comment= $form.find('[name="comment"]').val();

$.ajax({
                    url: 'http://kpakpa.com/prefactuur/' + projectnr + '/' + termijnnr + '/' + projectdeel + '/' + 'update',
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    data: {project: projectnr, projectpart: projectpart,  termnr: termnr, status: status, amount: amount, comment: commment},
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
 });


**Controller**

public function update(Request $request){

            $data = Input::all();
            $project = $data['project'];
            $projectpart = $data['projectpart'];
            $termnr = $data['termnr'];

$project= $this->project->where(array('project' => $project, 'projectpart' =>       $projectpart, 'termnr' => $termnr))->first();

//What i want to change
            $project->status = $data['status'];
            $project->amount = $data['amount'];
            $prefac->comment = $data['comment'];

      $project->save
```

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: If you are getting a 500 server error then the error will be logged, what does the error message say?

Comment: I am using console.log($data) in my javascript code and the only log message I get is the 500 server error. expanding it only only points to this line of code in jquery (xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );.

Comment: solved my problem.. There was a typo in my code. on one of the fields I was trying to update.